# Wordpress if has tag or in category

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

```
<?php if (has_tag('abc') && (in_category('d')) { echo '<div class="xxx">' ; } else { echo '<div class="yyy">' ; } ; ?>
```

Im using the above but it returns an error, am i doing anything wrong? Thanks for looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parentheses `)` in your if statement.

Fix it to this:

```
<?php if ( has_tag('abc') && (in_category('d')) ) { echo '<div class="xxx">' ; } else { echo '<div class="yyy">' ; } ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your code try this

```
<?php if ( has_tag('abc') && in_category('d') ) { echo '<div class="xxx">'; } else { echo '<div class="yyy">'; } ?>
```

has_tag and in_category only works in Wordpress **loop** if you do not pass post id as second parameter.